# List Style Conflicting CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using the code below to generate a side menu, But wherever I include the menu, all the list icons on those pages also disapear...

How can I limit the list style changes to this php file only, or change the css so that it only applies to this UL?

```
<style type="text/css">
ul li li:before {
    content: none !important;
    font-size:100px;
}

.art-postcontent ul>li:before, .art-post ul>li:before, .art-textblock ul>li:before{
    content:none !important;    
}

.art-postcontent ul>li, .art-post ul>li, .art-textblock ul>li{
    padding-left:0px !important;    
}
</style>
<div class="art-vmenublock clearfix" style="width:100%">
        <div class="art-vmenublockheader" style="width:100%">
            <h3 class="t">Welcome <br/> <? echo $full_name; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="art-vmenublockcontent" style="width:100%">
<ul class="art-vmenu leftmenu" style="margin-top: -2px; margin-left: -1px;">
    <li><a href="index.php/my-account" <? if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/index.php/my-account'){echo 'class="active"';}?> >Dashboard</a>
        <? /* <ul class="active">
            <li><a href="main/new-page.html">New Page</a>
            </li>
                <li><a href="main/new-page-2.html">New Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="main/new-page-3.html">New Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>*/?>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php/my-account/companies" <? if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/index.php/my-account/companies'){echo 'class="active"';}?> >Companies</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php/my-account/logout">Log-Out</a></li>       
       </ul>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use id or class for this ul only and change any related style to use this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `ul` an `id` attribute with a value of say, `no-list-style` and then change any references to `ul` in your CSS to be `ul#no-list-style`.

Your `<ul>` tag would now be

```
<ul id="no-list-style" class="art-vmenu leftmenu" style="margin-top: -2px; margin-left: -1px;">
```

and your CSS would now be

```
ul#no-list-style li li:before {
    content: none !important;
    font-size:100px;
}

.art-postcontent ul#no-list-style>li:before, .art-post ul#no-list-style>li:before, .art-textblock ul#no-list-style>li:before{
    content:none !important;    
}

.art-postcontent ul#no-list-style>li, .art-post ul#no-list-style>li, .art-textblock ul#no-list-style>li{
    padding-left:0px !important;    
}
```

Comment: so for example `.art-postcontent ul>li:before, .art-post ul>li:before, .art-textblock ul>li:before` would be `.art-postcontent ul#no-list-style>li:before, .art-post ul#no-list-style>li:before, .art-textblock ul#no-list-style>li:before`?

Comment: That's correct! I'll edit my answer just to make it a little more verbose.